# what's the different between ///<reference path="..."/> and import statement

Tags: reactjs, typescript

at first when I import react, the typescript compiler console 'can not find module react',then I add /// , and the problem fixed.

but I just found if I remove the reference comment, there is no error.

this is my code:

```js
/**
 * Created by huagu on 2015/12/21.
 */
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";
import FloatButton from "./FloatButton";

window.onload = function (event:Event) {
    var bd = document.querySelector('#bd');
    var style:__React.CSSProperties = {
        width:'80px',
        height:'40px',
        background:'blue',
        position:'absolute',
        top:'100px',
        left:'10px'
    }
    var str:__React.CSSProperties = '';
    var num:number = '';
    var c = <span style={{fontSize:'14px'}}>button</span>
    var props = {
        content:c,
        click:function(){
            console.log("FloatButton clicked");
        },
        style:style,
        allowSeriesClick:false,
    }
    ReactDOM.render(<FloatButton {...props}></FloatButton>, bd);
}
```

so, my problem is whether reference comment is necessary?I don't add reference comment, but there is no error reference __React.CSSProperties, it was declare in react.d.ts. if it's not necessary, why there is no error with "var str:__React.CSSProperties = ''; "?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`///<reference>` is the equivalent of saying "Just trust me that this will have run before my code", which is often something you can safely assume. It's intended for IDEs, and since it's a comment, does not affect code execution at all.

`import modulename ...` uses either commonjs or requirejs to actually retrieve the specified module before running the proceeding code.

If you have a dependency-management system that works with the module you need, it's preferred to use that instead of the former solution; that way, there is no risk of trying to access a module before it's loaded (even if 99% of uses aren't even remotely possible for the code to see before it has loaded)

Comment: I think a better way to put it is that /// <reference> is at compilation time, while import statements are at runtime as well.

Comment: @toskv Well, import statements can also be at compile time. Reference statements theoretically shouldn't change the actual compiled output either (since plain JavaScript code never really depends on knowing the types of the code it's operating on). It's mostly an assistive technology, much like the "#pragma region"s used by Visual Studio.

Comment: indeed, import statements are both at runtime and compilation time. References are one way of telling the compiler what files it should compile. I would go for a tsconfig file instead though. :)

Comment: thanks, but why there is no error with    var style:React.CSSProperties = ‘str’;

Comment: well.. what is the type of CSSProperties?

Comment: interface CSSProperties{key?:value}  all of the keys is optional